# Applying a function for csv files having more than 10 rows in R

Tags: r, csv

Following is the code that I've written for applying moving average forecast to all the `.csv` files in a directory.

```
fileNames <- Sys.glob("*.csv")
for (fileName in fileNames) {      
  abc <- read.csv(fileName, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  nrows <- sapply(fileNames, function(f) nrow(read.csv(f)))  
  if (nrows>=as.vector(10)) {
    library(stats)
    library(graphics)
    library(forecast)
    library(TTR)
    library(zoo)
    library(tseries)
    abc1 = abc[,1]
    abc1 = t(t(abc1))
    abc1 = as.vector(abc1)
    abc2 = ts(abc1, frequency = 12,start = c(2014,1))
    abc_decompose = decompose(abc2)
    plot(abc_decompose)
    forecast = (abc_decompose$trend)
    x <- data.frame(abc, forecast)
    write.csv (x, file = fileName, row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE)
  }
}
```

Now when I exclude line 5, i.e. `if(nrows>=as.vector(10))` the code is working fine on files which has enough no. of entries (I had taken around 20 files all having more than 10 rows).

But, I have some csv files in the directory which contains 2 or less than 2 entries, so when the code runs on the whole directory it's giving the following error message: 
`Error in decompose(abc2) : time series has no or less than 2 periods`. As excluding those files manually is hard, I have to use something like line 5.

Now nrows is giving me a list of all the file names of the directory with their no. of rows, but when I run the whole code I'm getting 148 warning messages (that directory has 148 csv files), each one saying:
`In if (nrows >= as.vector(10)) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` and I'm not getting the output.

So, definitely I'm doing something wrong in that line 5. Please help.

Comment: Do you realise that every time through the `for` loop, you are first reading in the "current" file (i.e. `fileName`), but then also reading in _all_ of the files (with the `sapply`). Maybe you meant to just check the number of rows of `fileName`? In which case you should remove the `sapply` line, and change your `if` condition to `if(nrow(abc) >= 10) {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `nrows <- sapply(fileNames, function(f) nrow(read.csv(f)))` to:

```
nrows <- nrow(abc)
```

Why do you need to take the number of rows in all files at each iteration. The error is telling you what is going wrong. It is **using the number of rows in the first file every time**.